# Direct And Indirect Recursion Issue

Tags: c++, recursion

So I'm Having A Recursion Bug.

OutPut I Want...

> Input 4
>   
>   * * * *
>   
>   * * *
>   
>   * *
>   
>   *
>   
>   * *
>   
>   * * *
>   
>   * * * *

OutPut I Get..

> Input 4
>   
>   * Big Blank Space*

I Cant Seem To Wrap My Head Very Well Around recursion.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<windows.h>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int i;
bool end = false;
int changer = -1;
int placeHolder;
bool recursionUp(int num1)
{
    if(num1 == placeHolder)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for(i = placeHolder; i == num1; i--)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    recursionUp(num1 + 1);
}

bool cont = false;
int recursion(int num1)
{
    if(num1 == 0)
    {
        cont = recursionUp(num1);
    }
    for(i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    recursion(num1 - 1);
    if(cont)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Input Star Number...\n";
    cout << "\t Input: ";
    cin >> number;
    placeHolder = number;
    recursion(number);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: You Need Not Capitalize Every Word :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any recursion there are two things you'll need to define:

1. The end condition
2. A `depth` value (and any other information that's needed)

In your case the end condition is when `depth == number - 1`

You'll want to print before and after each recursion.

```
void recursion(int depth){
    if (depth <= 1) {
        cout << '*' << endl << endl;
    }else{
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i)cout << "* ";
        cout << endl << endl;
        recursion(depth - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i)cout <<"* ";
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
}
```